# UITableViewCell layer property does not adapt after autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

recently I'm working on a project where I load a custom cell from a NIB file.
In the nib file of the cell I set the constraints correctly and all its content is loaded in the right position as you can see in the screen

[image]

The problem is related to the 2px grey border you can see under each cell.

I don't want to use the native separator but add a border to the layer of every cell.
The border is added to the cell but it extends for the nib file width but after adding the cell to the table every cell stretch its width.

I'm forced to add programmatically a border because I need to change its color and thickness and also because I don't want to see the native separator on empty cells.

Comment: where you add it , also set separator style to none ??

Comment: show the code where you're adding the border in your cell.

Answer (score 0):

self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none

if you are using the InterfaceBuilder,  you can set the tableView's separator property to None

[image]